# How to return value from datagridview

Tags: datagridview, vb.net-2010

I would like to return a value from a table that has a datagridview from the selected row

```
TextBox8.Text = Me.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells("Vend Price").ToString
```

vend price represent the needed column name.

I get the error message:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Now what have i done wrong?

p.s. is it possible to return a value from a removed column of the datagrid or i shall return directly from the table?

---

More complete code is below:

```
Private Sub MainMenu_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load    
    Me.ProductsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.MisuDBDataSet.Products) 
End Sub 

Private Sub Button15_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button15.Click   
    If Me.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells("Vend Price").Value.ToString Is Nothing Then 
        'Do nothing 
    Else 
        Label13.Text = Me.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells("Vend Price").Value.ToString 
    End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: please provide your html markup.

Comment: @Nudier the datagridview is a winforms control, not asp.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value out of a `DataGridView` cell you need to reference that cell's `Value` property:

```
TextBox8.Text = Me.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells("Vend Price").Value.ToString
```

Comment: I've given the syntax for getting the value, though looking again, I doubt your code would cause an object reference error. What do you mean when you say you have "removed a column from the datagrid"?

Comment: Regarding the column from datagrid, i have created a datagrid that only shows a few colums from the db table, and i was wondering if the grid actualy has all the columns informations or only the shown ones.

Comment: @MisuEgri what do you mean "only shows"? how do you stop it showing the column? Though, referencing an incorrect column name causes a different error anyway.

Comment: @MisuEgri - and is current row null? You need to break that line apart and find what is throwing the object reference not set error.

Comment: Hi David, the grid take the data from the productsbindingsource and on the datagridview tasks i edit the columns and remove some of the columns, because i don't need them all to be showns in this datagrid.

Comment: @MisuEgri And how do you fill the binding source with data? You need to give more code (preferably the minimal code to reproduce the issue) to have any hope of getting an answer.

Comment: so i click on a cell or line in the data grid, then made a label that take the text value of the requested column of the selected line as mentioned and the error pops up. The troubleshoot tips are "use the new keyword to create an object instance and "check to determine if the object is null before calling the method.

Comment: well the bindigsource was created automaticly whn i selected a table from the dbs dataset

Comment: @MisuEgri show the code. Do you do this text box assignment within a cell click event, within a button handler, somewhere else?  do you populate the binding source? This won't happen magically. All this detail is important, so we need to see the code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15816/discussion-between-david-hall-and-misu-egri)

Comment: Private Sub MainMenu_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
       Me.ProductsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.MisuDBDataSet.Products)
 end sub

Private Sub Button15_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button15.Click
        If Me.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells("Vend Price").Value.ToString Is Nothing Then
            'Do nothing
        Else
            Label13.Text = Me.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells("Vend Price").Value.ToString
        End If
    End Sub

Comment: @MisuEgri Put this in the question not as a comment. I've started a chat room to help with this.

Answer (score 0):

To get the value out of a DataGridView cell you need to reference that cell's Value property:

```
Dim ColumnIndex As Integer = 0 Dim RowIndex As Integer = 0
ColumnIndex = DataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells("DataGridViewTextBoxColumn3").ColumnIndex
RowIndex = DataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells("DataGridViewTextBoxColumn3").RowIndex
TextBox8.Text = DataGridView(ColumnIndex, RowIndex).Value.ToString()
```

'My column name is `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn3` Hope this helps name property Should be set in the code somewhere check form properities for DataGridView Name and use it